# QGIS Modeler Input WMTS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, qgis-modeler, wmts

Maybe I'm just missing something here, but i can't figure out how to set a WMTS Layer as an Input Parameter in QGIS Modeler. I just wanted batch the process of exporting a GeoTiff from a WMTS Layer. Now it takes like 4 steps or so to do it. Since I use that a lot, I wanted to make it a little Model. Anyway I am not to good with Python, so I tried Modeler.